# Asp.net reuseable control, when directly clicking on file is downloaded with file extension .ashx

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-controls

I have an asp.net reusable control when directly clicking on file is downloaded with file extension .ashx, that happening only on IE, and its working fine on firefox.
[image: This is what i' am getting]
This is how im calling the Control:

```
<a data-fancybox-type="iframe" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="fileName" href="AttachmentControl/DownloadAttachment.ashx?SourceId=6&id=1&attachmentSource=download"><i class="fa fa-file-image-o"></i> <span>fileName</span></a>
```

**This Control is calling a WCF Service as bellow:**

```
AttachmentSvc.IAttachmentService clientDownload = new AttachmentSvc.AttachmentServiceClient();
AttachmentSvc.DownloadRequest requestData = new AttachmentSvc.DownloadRequest();

AttachmentSvc.RemoteFileInfo fileInfo = new AttachmentSvc.RemoteFileInfo();
requestData.FileName = fileName;
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(requestData.FileName))
{
  fileInfo = clientDownload.DownloadFile(requestData);
  byte[] arrayFile = ReadFully(fileInfo.FileByteStream);
  file = Convert.ToBase64String(arrayFile);
}
```

**And the code for the wcf service itself is the following:**

```
RemoteFileInfo result = new RemoteFileInfo();
var templateDestinationFolderPath = PSSConfigHelper.AttachmentsUrlPrimaryNode();
string filePath = Path.Combine(@templateDestinationFolderPath, request.FileName);
System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(filePath);

// check if exists
if (!fileInfo.Exists) throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("File not found", request.FileName);

// open stream
System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);

// return result
result.FileName = request.FileName;
result.Length = fileInfo.Length;
result.FileByteStream = stream;
```